# Standalone install for file like go run myfile.go

Tags: go, build, installation

I have a go project that consists of separate files (each having a main function) inside the project folder. Initially it was meant to be run as `go run file1.go`. But now I need a build for it like regular projects. Creating separate project for each file feels dumb.

The `go run` compiles input file into a temporary executable and executes it. What is the compilation step that `go run` does. I need to install different files as separate executables (with a name given by me). Can anyone give the steps on how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)? You use `go build` or `go install`.

Comment: @JimB I use go install for almost all projects. For this I want to know what directives I must use to get the desired effect - choose file as install source and name of the output executable.

Comment: Normally one would just create a subdir for each main file (putting them under another directory called `cmd/` is common), and `go install` each of those by import path. If you want to build each file directly, why not just `go build -o binfile file1.go`?

Comment: @JimB If I put one inside a `dir` inside cmd and then install, what will be the name of installed executable - the name of the `dir` ?

Comment: yes. (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cmd for a random example using this structure)

Comment: @JimB I put all the files in their respective folders. I have just one problem when I run `go install` from parent of cmd it shows 'no buildable Go source files', but when i run from cmd subdirectory it runs but only that one. How to install for every directory in cmd.

Comment: `go install import/path/...` (with the correct `import/path` of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the comments, you can use

```
go install ./...
```

If your working directory is not where all your packages are currently located, use

```
go install path/to/your/packages/...
```

The important thing are the three dots "...", indicating you want to build and install all packages from sub-directories as well.

This will create executables of all your packages in $GOPATH/bin/ .

Comment: Also add the use of cmd subdirectory in the project, which I didnt know and is not mentioned in golang documentation.